# How to apply same transformations on eval_set while using Pipeline()?

Tags: model, classification, pipeline

Below is pipeline I created for a classification problem:

```
categorical_preprocessing = Pipeline(
[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
])


numerical_preprocessing = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
])


preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(
                    [
                        ('catecorical', categorical_preprocessing,
                         make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)),
                        ('numerical', numerical_preprocessing,
                         make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)),
                    ])

#Resampling
over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.1)

classifier = XGBClassifier(n_estimators = 200)


model = Pipeline(steps = [
    ('preprocessor', preprocessing),
    ('resampling', over),
    ('classifier', classifier )
])
```

[The pipeline looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rq8p.png)

I want to draw loss curves for the train and eval set. I could use this code to get the evaluation metrics:

```
evalset  =[(X_train, Y_train),(X_test, Y_test)]

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, classifier__eval_metric = 'logloss', classifier__eval_set = evalset)
```

I figured out I need to apply the Pipeline transformations excluding the last step (XGBClassifier) on the eval_set as well. However, I need to apply smote only on X_train and not X_test.

How to proceed with this? And are there any errors till this step?